# Type Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setVisibility(int) from the type View

Tags: java, android

I keep getting the following error in Eclipse:

> Type Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setVisibility(int) from the type View

My code is:

```
package com.example.testing;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onLoveButtonClicked(View view) {
    TextView haikuTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.haikuTextView);
    TextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //error here
}
 }
```

I'm only a beginner at java so I don't know what's causing that problem. I have googled the error but I don't get anything that helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
haikuTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

`TextView` is the class and `haikuTextView` is your variable. You cannot change the visibility of an entire class. But you can change the visibility of your variable.

---

When you wrote:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/haikuTextView"
    ... />
```

you created one *instance* of the `TextView` class. You can create a lot of instances of the `TextView` class, but when you want to change some feature about a particular in one instance you have to specify which `TextView` you want to change.

When you wrote `TextView.setVisibility()` you tried to change *every* `TextView`. Now the `TextView` class doesn't have a method `setVisibility()` to change every `TextView`, but it does have `setVisibilty()` to change *one* instance.

**So**
When you try to access every `TextView` with `TextView.setVisibility()` this is a "static reference" but, like I said, there is no method to call `setVisibility()` *every* `TextView`.

If you use `haikuTextView.setVisibilty()` to change the visibility of one instance, this will work because this is "non-static method" exists.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Sam's answer:

TextView is a class; it's also a subclass of the View class.  When you refer to static members of a class, you do "classname.method(...)" or "classname.field"; when you say "TextView.setVisibility", you're making a "static reference" to the method "setVisibility" in the "View" class, which is inherited by the TextView class.  Thus, the error message: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setVisibility(int) from the type View. Because the setVisibility method isn't a static method; it's an ordinary method.

Ordinary methods have to be referred to relative to a specific *instance* of the class.  Since haikuTextView is an instance of TextView; you can say:

```
haikuTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Is that clear?

Comment: Yes thanks :) I was following a book and the book had textView.  I thought it was a typo. Thanks both of ye! :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//A small t instead of a capital T.
```

Best of Luck